# Bash Whitespace being calculated

Tags: bash, hash, sha256, sha

I am having issues with this script taking using the whitespace from my file that contains a list of words with each word on a separate line, I have double check and after each word there is a simple (return) no space yet the script is still calculating with whitespace

ok at that hash then type in:

"hello
"
So hello followed by enter to start a new line. Look at that hash value
That is what I am getting a hash value that is a sting + the enter. As a result my script isnt working the way it is supposed to. Can anyone help.

Answer (score 1):

echo outputs with enter

You can use

```
 echo -n "$test2" | sha256sum
```

Comment: Sorry that didnt help. :(
The purpose of this script is to taking in a hash and compare it to a list of common password and then output what password it is